# Node load balancer using http proxy slower than original server

Tags: node.js, load-balancing, node-http-proxy

I have a web service built in delphi and I built a load balancer using [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) module for scaling the webservice.

When I'm receiving a lot of requests (using [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) with 100 threads) I lost performance. If make a request to the port of the original webservice it responds too much faster than when a I make the same request for the node load balancer's port.

I've tried to set maxSockets = 10000

```
var agent = new http.Agent();
agent.maxSockets = 10000;
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({aget: agent});
```

and I've tried it too

```
  var agent = new http.Agent();
  agent.maxSockets = 10000;
  proxy.web(req, res, { 
    target: {
        host: server.host,
        port: server.port
      },
      agent: agent
    });
```

but the problems still exists

I thought to use the node clusters but there's a bug when using windows. [This one](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2398), and I can't find the files they tell to edit to fix the bug.

Does someone have any idea that I can apply?